# Create dynamic link id from while loop

Tags: php, jquery

I have a script where I need to create a dynamic id from each record retrieved from mysql. At the moment I am using the `<a>` tag for testing using `#` in href and would be happy if this could achieved using links.

The other problem is once these id's are created I need to be able to select them from jquery click event and the result placed in #div2. I have posted code for php and would be grateful if someone could help.

Assume this code working as is. Many thanks

```
<div style="width: 33%; height: auto; float:left;">
    <?php
    $inboxnum_rows = mysqli_num_rows($inboxresult);
    if(!$inboxnum_rows) {
    echo 'No reults to display';
    } else {
    while ($inboxrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($inboxresult)) {
    $date = $inboxrow["date_frm"];
    $date = strtotime( $date );
    $date = date( 'd/m/Y H:i:s', $date );
    $from = $inboxrow["from_frm"];
    $subject = $inboxrow["subject_frm"];
    echo '<div style="margin-right: 6px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #ccc; height: auto;">';
    echo '<span style="font-weight: bold;">' . $from . '</span>';
    echo '<br />';
    echo "<a href='#'>" .$subject. "</a>" . '<span style="float: right;">' .$date. '</span>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
    }
    ?>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" style="width: 65%; height: auto; padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ccc; float:left;">
    No new mail selected or to display
    </div>
```

Comment: please elaborate a bit. In the question, you nowhere seem to create any `Id` and for your second question please show some jQuery code.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri I have no jquery code until i figure out how to create dynamic id and select with click event. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using ajax. Just posted the id and did a lookup. Many thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution for this:

1. Use `$inboxresult["id"]` as "id"s you need create in `<a>` tag
2. For JS, if you do not use js in PHP templating, you should use `"data-name-id"` attribute to catch target id on `click` event.

Wrap:

PHP:

...

`echo "<a class='need-example-action' href='#' data-example-id='" .$inboxresult["id"]. "'>" .$subject. "</a>" . '<span style="float: right;">' .$date. '</span>';`

...

JS:

```
$(".need-example-action").click(function(e) {
    alert(e.getAttribute("data-example-id"));
    // anything
});
```

Hope this help

Comment: thans for reply. However, i am getting `fatal error  Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array`. Loop works fine if I use my original code. Thanks

Comment: Think your code is incorrect. It is creating the same id for each link and in the js click event i get error with `e.getAttribute is not a function`, Thanks

Comment: What could be the problem. I have the correct id call from db? Thanks

Comment: Do you use jQuery for your project? Or can you show me your JS libs?